# Gitlab Merge Request When To Approve

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

So we're having a little bit of a debate where I work as to what point should a reviewer "Approve" a Merge Request.

We have setup some Gitlab Pipelines to run and carry out what I would say are fairly standard stuff *(Build, Automated Tests, Sonar etc)*. Now we're trying to improve best practises across the department and a debate has started as to when the reviewer(s) should actually "Approve" the Merge Request.

We have the 1 argument that says the Pipeline acts as an "Approver" itself and if it fails it basically should prevent the Merge Request from happening, so it doesn't matter when the reviewer(s) hit that "Approve" button, because the reviewer(s) are reviewing the Code and not the pipeline.

And then you have another argument that says the reviewer(s) should not be "Approving" until the Pipeline passes, and they should be dependent on the Pipeline passing as to whether they should be "Approving" the Merge Request or not.

So should the reviewer(s) of a Merge Request wait until the the Gitlab Pipeline finishes and if the pipeline is successful then "Approve" or should they be able to "Approve" once they have reviewed the code, no matter if the pipeline has finished or not?

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to wait until the pipeline passes, review the code and then do an approval. If the pipeline doesn't pass in the first place, there is an issue and the developer needs to fix his/her PR before someone spends time to review it.